# How to pre processed the nominal data attributes in data mining?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining

[Dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pN71.png)I have done the one hot encoding on nominal data attributes but later i want to do clustering on the data so please suggest feasible solution. i am new to data mining

Comment: could you please provide more details with some sample data that clear the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: did you checked the answer ? was it helpful for you ?

Comment: yes i am still working on the algorithm part ..i think k-modes algorithm will be good for nominal data.

Comment: Yes, I checked that too, it will be good practice for you, Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering that you did not provide a proper information of your problem and it seems you are new to these concepts I provide an entire solution on a fake data. you can learn from it and get the points to work on your solution.

I have implemented in python and assume that you are familiar with skit-learn :

```
from numpy import array
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn import cluster
# define example
data = ['cold', 'cold', 'warm', 'cold', 'hot', 'hot', 'warm', 'cold', 'warm', 'hot']
values = array(data)
print(values)
# integer encode
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)
print(integer_encoded)
# binary encode
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
print(onehot_encoded)
# Clustering step:
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(onehot_encoded)
print(kmeans.labels_)
```

and here is the result :

> ['cold' 'cold' 'warm' 'cold' 'hot' 'hot' 'warm' 'cold' 'warm' 'hot']

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

cluster label for the above data is :

> [1 1 2 1 0 0 2 1 2 0]